# Scala read and parse JSON

Tags: java, json, scala

I am new to Scala. I have a JSON file, entitled `scala_input.json` containing two items:

```
{
 "edges_file": "/path/edges.json.gz", 
 "seed_file": "/path/seed.json.gz"
}
```

I wish to open the file, parse and attribute two `val` from this file. I have tried:

```
val input_file = "/path/scala_input.json"
val json_data = JSON.parseFull(input_file)
val edges_file = json_data.get.asInstanceOf[Map[String, Any]]("edges_file").asInstanceOf[String]
val seeds_file = json_data.get.asInstanceOf[Map[String, Any]]("seed_file").asInstanceOf[String]]
```

However, this returns `java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get`. What is it I have not defined? `json_data` and `input_file` are correct and I am sure that `edges_file` and `seed_file` exist.

Comment: Can you specify which JSON package you imported? I'm facing a similar issue. thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`JSON.parseFull` expects a JSON String, not a path to a file containing such a String. So - you should first load the file and then parse it:

```
val input_file = "./scala_input.json"
val json_content = scala.io.Source.fromFile(input_file).mkString
val json_data = JSON.parseFull(json_content)
// go on from there...
```

Comment: what library do I need to import to use JSON.parseFull?

Comment: I believe the required import is `import scala.util.parsing.json._` which is part of the Scala library

Answer (score 5):

[os-lib](https://github.com/lihaoyi/os-lib) and [upickle](https://github.com/lihaoyi/upickle) are better options for reading and parsing JSON data.

```scala
val jsonString = os.read(os.pwd/"src"/"test"/"resources"/"scala_input.json")
val data = ujson.read(jsonString)
data("edges_file").str // "/path/edges.json.gz"
data("seed_file").str // "/path/seed.json.gz"
```

This code is way cleaner than what `JSON.parseFull` allows for.  [See here](https://mungingdata.com/scala/read-write-json/) for more details on how to use these libs.